# NoBackendError: Opening m4a file using Python Librosa

Tags: python

I am trying to open an m4a file using librosa but keep geeting the NoBackendError when I use librosa.load. Any help on how I can fix the error? Error below:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import librosa
filename = 'file.m4a'
y, sr = librosa.load(filename)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoBackendError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-93a4f3277be0> in <module>()
      2 # 2. Load the audio as a waveform `y`
      3 #    Store the sampling rate as `sr`
----> 4 y, sr = librosa.load(filename)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py in load(path, sr, mono, offset, duration, dtype, res_type)
    110 
    111     y = []
--> 112     with audioread.audio_open(os.path.realpath(path)) as input_file:
    113         sr_native = input_file.samplerate
    114         n_channels = input_file.channels

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\audioread\__init__.py in audio_open(path)
    114 
    115     # All backends failed!
--> 116     raise NoBackendError()

NoBackendError:
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this means you have no codec for the format. 
Do you have ffmpeg oder gstreamer installed and in your path?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to install libav-tools.

> sudo apt-get install libav-tools

source: [github librosa](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/219#issuecomment-281811667)